# python crashes after import library (openpyxl)

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

[fixed!] 
Downgrading numpy to 1.15.0 fixed the problem. Thanks everyone for your input on the issue!

The program has 2 lines of code:

```
import openpyxl
print 'a'
```

when I try to run the program, python crashes on me.

[image: pythonw.exe has stopped working]

here is the problem detail:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    53b1ee1c
  Fault Module Name:    libopenblas.IPBC74C7KURV7CB2PKT5Z5FNR3SIBV4J.gfortran-win_amd64.
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5c3bd575
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 00000000010fecc1
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 4065
  Additional Information 2: 406514178a2b6e9aa40eed547759f454
  Additional Information 3: fc05
  Additional Information 4: fc05b10293ad572b4555c73505820972
```

Comment: hi snake, thanks for replying:). when i run it on cmd, it still shows me that python.exe has stopped working, without any error/warning message in the cmd window. I'm running python2.

Comment: Perhaps try downgrading your version of the library. Does it work when you don't import that? It could also be a corrupted binary file perhaps uninstall and then reinstall the package or it could be your hardware doesn't support the process. Perhaps you are running 64 bit code on 32 bit hardware or something like that

Comment: hi joe, thanks for replying! I've tried uninstall and reinstall the package, downgrade it to previous version (2.6.0), but it still crashes. I'm running it on a VM, the same code works on other VM with the same setup.. (all 64 bit), so this is really confusing lol..

Comment: I had the same error with Python 3.7 64bit on Windows Server 2012R2. Downgrading numpy to 1.15.0 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem with a Server2012 but the Server itself was not the reason.
Its the CPU and if that one is older and does not Support AVX512 this crash happens.
Downgrading works but is just a more or less dirty workaround.

The real reason is `OPENBLAS` and if you set the Environment Variable like this:

```
SET OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=haswell
```

it will work swimmingly.

More explanations to the exact reason can be found here.
https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/10379